# SharedPreferences and cheating in Android games

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, root, edit

Highscores in my game are currently stored in `SharedPreferences`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <long name="level_1_score" value="1000" />
    <long name="level_2_score" value="1100" />
</map>
```

Like this, the score can be manipulated on rooted devices.
(The xml file is pulled to PC, edited, and then pushed back to device).

What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: Why do you care if the user changes their own high scores on their own device?

Comment: The overall score is to be submitted to public leaderboards. This score is computed by summing up the individual level scores.

Comment: Then why is the value in `SharedPreferences` anything more than a local cache of data, where the system of record is the server?

Comment: The leaderboard is implemented by using "Google Play Game Services". In the game there is a leaderboard for the overall score, but not for individual levels. I don't know if it is possible to pull individual level scores from Google servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use sharedPreferences with `MODE_PRIVATE`, but if you want to be convinced you can hash names and values, and add some extra unused fields to detect if someone is trying to change preferences you will know. for example

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <long name="asdadadad" value="ASDASDASDAS" />
    <long name="asdadadadas" value="ADQOWI232DJQO1231" />
    <long name="level_1_score" value="1000" />
    <long name="level_2_score" value="1100" />
</map>
```

as you hashed names and values you will get picture like this one. when you decrypt asdadadad you will get `level_1_score` and when you decrypt `ASDASDASDAS` you will get some integer(written in string). 
If user changes hash it maybe decrypted as non integer value(that won't be possible to parse to integer)

None will be able to decrypt without knowing your hashing key, that  key will be saved as some constant field in your program.

And you can make some trap fields like this one, user may think that scores xml name is `level_1_score` but if user changes this , you can catch user for cheating. (Because it's unused one)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way may be using PreferenceObfuscator from Google's App Licensing library. This can still be beaten by decompiling your app but the barrier is much higher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even in MODE_PRIVATE, a rooted device apps can access your Shared Prefs. Worst still, with the same UID as your game app's shared prefs can be edited to.

However, why don't you try encrypting it!? ;)

Make sure to keep the key on a server.

Comment: If you save the key on server, you must provide https connection :D or user can catch traffic with 'wireshark' like program, than decrypt it. 

But who will do it for a game? O.o

Comment: Yea there is always a way. But this would safeguard from most crackers, since key won't be hardcoded in the code. if someone gets hands on apk of the game they can unwrap the classes and find the key..

Comment: Yes the best you can do is to prevent users from easily cracking your code.